# signtool.exe not found in vs2008

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to publish a program in vs2008 but I get the following error,

- can not publish because a project failed to build.
- An error occurred while signing: signtool.exe not found.

I've been searching Google for some time now but I can't find the answer.

I can't find signtool.exe; can anyone tell me where I can get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548342/an-error-occurred-while-signing-signtool-exe-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

`signtool.exe` is included with the Windows SDK, and a copy of the Windows SDK is included with VS2008.

It should be installed as `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\signtool.exe`, but it might depend on installation options.

Another route is to install the Windows SDK directly (latest version includes Win7/2008R2 support).

Comment: hi, I installed vs2008 but I can't find the signtool under the above directory, even when I search for it nothing gets found.

Comment: Ensure you install the Win32 SDK tools. (Not sure exactly which option will drive the installation of SDK tools, you might need to try a few options.)

Answer (score 1):

VS 2008 - This tool is located at,

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could find in any one of this location.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\Bin

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin