# An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

While I was trying to Update my Project I was making - I got an error for the first time I've seen:

> 'An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found.'

I've never seen this before, So I looked up that SignTool.exe is what signs my project for ClickOnce Deployment.

I also read that is it a part of Windows SDK - but when I looked to find where SignTool.exe is - I saw it right there!

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
```

I saw no problem, and I've always published my Project all the time - I'm on Version 68. But this is the first time I've seen this - I didn't touch any options that would do this.

Any help?

Comment: Do you have a few versions of Visual Studio on your machine and ran few different versions recently?

Comment: I'm using windows developer preview, is that it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now try to publish the ClickOnce application. If you still find the same issue, please check if you installed the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview on the system. The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview is a prerelease version of the .NET Framework, and should not be used in production scenarios. It is an in-place update to the .NET Framework 4. You would need to uninstall this prerelease product from ARP.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2013/11/18/an-error-occurred-while-signing-signtool-exe-not-found/

Lastly you might want to install the customer preview instead of being on the developer preview

Comment: Updated with new version

Comment: The correct answer is of der_meister and Alex Erygin

Comment: outdated answer

Answer (score 194):

ClickOnce Publishing Tools are not installed as part of the Typical Installation Options. So you have to install it in advanced mode.
[image: ClickOnce installation]

This dialog can be found in Windows 7 by going to  *Control Panel > Uninstall a program*, right-clicking on *Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015* and selecting `Change`. A Visual Studio dialog will open up. Select `Modify` from the set of buttons at the bottom and the above dialog will appear.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me in Windows10. In Control Panel I've updated the installation to include CickOnce Publishing Tools and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: This is the correct answer for people having problems with this in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: The command line version is:
**. "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{90ac7cb6-f7f2-49d1-aa5d-d159d8e86e19}\vs_professional.exe" /InstallSelectableItems ClickOnceV1 /S**

Answer (score 65):

Please Click Once application --> Properties --> Signing -> Unchecked the Sign the ClickOnce manifests.

Problem will be solved.

Note: Be aware that this solution removes security from your project. Seek assitance from a more learned colleague before doing so.

Comment: This is very bad solution.

Comment: I am a fairy experienced programmer in Java and Python. I needed to compile a C# project in VS2015 for my own use. This is the only solution I could understand (with the help of Google) on this page.

Comment: @AlexErygin, why is this a bad solution?

Comment: This is not a solution - there is a reason that ClickOnce programs are signed: it's a security feature, not something there to annoy developers

Comment: @chiffa could you expand on what you didn't understand about Der_Meister's correct answer?

Comment: @DanielGee, ClickOnce auto updates will stop work. If you disable signing and publish application, installed applications will not detect a new version.

Comment: I don't use the ClickOnce to deploy my applications, I'm just trying to build the exe for debugging. Is there any reason I should worry about the ClickOnce signing?

Comment: This answer relates to "ignore security and help my users become infected". This should NOT be the solution you go with. If you don't care about signing an installer, then you should remove the installer/publish settings instead of disabling security!!

Comment: This is a good solution since I just write a small tool for personal usage. I think it should be: "Right click on your project - Properties - Signing - Uncheck Sign ClickOne manifest". At first I don't know how to "Please Click Once application", it's confused with ClickOnce Tools :D

Comment: I would upvote you ten times if I could. That is the problem of .Net platform, they add thing you sometimes don't need at all! That is why Node.js is taking over. .Net just sucks.

Answer (score 23):

SignTool is moved to another location in the last SDK: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86`

Need to install ClickOnce Publishing Tools during Visual Studio 2015 setup.

You can re-run the Installation from the Programs and Features section; find Visual Studio in the list and click Change.

Comment: I'm using windows 10, I can't find SignTool anywhere. I must uncheck "Sign the ClickOne manifests" to avoid this error.

Comment: I use Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. SignTool was installed when I added ClickOnce Publishing Tools package in VS setup.

Comment: @Der_Meister have you succesfully publish anything ?

Comment: This is the correct answer - dissapointing that "Don't Sign" and "reinstall .NET" are higher up :(

Comment: In case it's not obvious to anyone, re-running the installer will allow you to add in extra features to your VS install - it's very clear once it's open.

Answer (score 18):

You can fix this by clicking on installation application of VS. Then click Modify > Mark ClickOnce App and then upgrade your VS. Also i think @Alex Erygin is right. **It is a bad solution to** *Click Once application --> Properties --> Signing -> Uncheck Sign the ClickOnce manifests.* This is not a solution. It only circumambulated the problem.

Comment: circumambulated

Answer (score 11):

This is a simple fix. Open the project you are getting this error on. Click "Project" at the top. Then click " Properties" ( Will be the name of the opened project) then click "Security" then uncheck "Enable ClickOnce security settings."

That should fix everything.

Comment: Your fix worked in our environment where the code is shared between developers using SVN

Comment: Not working but when clicked on Signing -> Unchecked [Sign the ClickOnce manifests] is now working...

Comment: Quick fix. Thanks!

Comment: _"That should fix everything"_ - except for keeping security

Answer (score 9):

Click "Project" at the top. Then click " Properties" -> Signing -> Unchecked [Sign the ClickOnce manifests] is now working

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers above talk about *disabling* ClickOnce.  In my situation, I never used ClickOnce for my applications but after I upgraded to VS 2015 it was suddenly enabled and I got the 'SignTool.exe not found' error when I tried to compile.

To disable you go into the properties of your Project (right click) and choose *Security | Uncheck Enable ClickOnce security settings*.

You can leave the manifest checked in the Signing tab because it has nothing to sign if it's been disabled.

I've confirmed that unchecking the security resolved the compile error on my projects.

Comment: you have clickonce publishing enabled, all you did was remove it's security.

Answer (score 2):

I needed Signing hence couldn't un-check as suggested.

Then goto Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Click Change then the installer will load and you need to click Modify to add ClickOnce Publishing Tools feature.

Answer (score 1):

I did have similar problem. For some reason under 
project properties -> Signing -> Sign ClickOnce manifests was enabled.

I unchecked it and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling SDK did not help me but installing SDK+.NET 3.5 did from link below:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 users can find `signtool.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64` folder (`10.0.18362.0` in my case, or other version).

---

But first, make sure you've installed [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Then, check `Windows SDK Signing Tools for Desktop Apps` is installed by going to `Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features`, choose Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.18362.1 (in my case, you version may be different), right-click, choose `Change`, choose options `Change` then click `Next`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue/error message just after upgrading Visual Studio Pro 2019 V16.6.0. Solution was to make sure that the signing certificate is valid as mine had expired by a day.

Look in properties and signing to either enter a valid or temporary certificate. To keep the file name the same as before then un-click the security as mentioned above and then delete the key file linked to the programme.

Create a new key file and then add back the security.

Answer (score 1):

1. Solution Explorer
2. Your app Right Clik
3. Propatis
4. Security
5. Unchek (Enable ClickOnce Security Settings)
   Thats Solve..... __:)
6. https://i.stack.imgur.com/62nKZ.png See

[enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading build tools in DevOps build agent to visual studio 2019, we started getting the below error for 64-bit build step of a WPF application.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3975,5): error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe was not found at path

I tried all the above answers except the ones to disable signing or signing security and nothing helped.

Disabled the default MSBUILD step
[image]

Added a cmd prompt step
[image]

The path is 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MsBuild.exe"

**Note**: Removed **amd64** from the path above.

This is still a workaround. I hope Microsoft will fix it in the following release.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2019 or later (Windows 11)

**Option 1 (Recommended) -**

ClickOnce Publishing Tools are not installed basic Installation. Therefore you will have to manually check and install.

Go to Visual Studio Installer
[image: Go to Visual Studio Installer]

Then Click modify
[image: Modify]

Finally, select Individual components tab, search for ClickOnce Publishing and  install

[image: Install]

Restart the computer.

**Option 2 (Not recommended) -**

Click Once application --> Properties --> Signing -> Uncheck Sign the ClickOnce manifests. This is not a solution. A workaround.

[image]

Option 3 -

Install [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). Check `Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Windows Software Development Kit`