# Why getting exception SignTool.exe was not found at path?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe was not found at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\signtool.exe.   FileDownloader

I tried to change the .net from 3.5 to 4.5 same error when compiling.

I tried to read in this answer in the link that i need to publish my project or to update something i didn't understand why and how to do it. I don't want to publish my project yet.

[Link for some answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548342/an-error-occurred-while-signing-signtool-exe-not-found)

Comment: Solution was to uncheck the 'Sign ClickOnce Manifests' in the 'Signing' tab in the program properties.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple solution though; edit your Visual Studio settings and make sure the ClickOnce components are selected, see below:

[image]